# DMA access to DWT registers

Tags: arm, embedded, cortex-m

I'm wrapping my head around the following question:

is it possible to access the registers of the [DWT unit](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.100165_0201_00_en/ric1417175941906.html) in Cortex-M devices with a DMA transfer?

My intention is to get readings of the DWT_CPICNT register without executing instructions on the core.

Comment: Is DWT listed into your DMA sources table on SoC manual ?

Comment: you assume dma does not interrupt the core? not always the case (in general across all platforms, would have to research this core to know)

Comment: @LPs there are only different AHB/APB peripherals and memory listed. From the documents I would not assume its possible nor impossible.

Comment: @dwelch I rephrased the statement to "without running instructions on the core"

Comment: You got your answer then.

Comment: @LPs no, not yet. your assumption would be it's not possible?

Comment: If DMA, on your SoC, is not designed to access that specific register/memory/device, you will not use it to do what you want. Manual (apart from errors) gives you the list of sources applicable to DMA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the general description of the Core's debug subsystems [elsewhere in the TRM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/Bcgbfdhc.html) (emphasis mine):

> All the debug components exist on the **internal Private Peripheral Bus** (PPB) and can be accessed using privileged code.

A look at the topology in the [block diagram](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0337e/Bcgigedh.html#Bcghdbba) also makes it pretty clear that these are internal to the debug layer wrapped around the core, and it's only the core itself and the external debug port which have any access.

As @LPs points out, even it it *were* an external block there's still no guarantee that it would be a valid DMA target, as that would further depend on the DMA controller and the interconnects within the SoC - only the manual for that particular SoC can tell you what the DMA has access to.